# (Fine uploader) Error uploading file to s3 using external ec2 server as signature handler

Tags: python, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I been struggling for a couple of days trying to get this working. So now I thought I'd ask for some help.

I'm not able to sign headers and I don't know how to proceed. I have followed this guide to every detail: https://blog.fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser-3d9dcdcc0f33#sign-policy

This is my setup:

Javascript to handle upload:

```
      var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
      element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
      debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: 'my-bucket.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com',
            accessKey: 'my-access-key'
        },
        signature: {
          endpoint: 'my-external-signature-server'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: 'my-external-signature-server/s3/success'
        },
        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ["jpeg", "jpg", "png"],
            acceptFiles: "image/jpeg, image/png",
            sizeLimit: 10000000,
            itemLimit: 1
        },
        retry: {
           enableAuto: true // defaults to false
        },
        paste: {
            targetElement: document,
            promptForName: true
        }
    });
```

Server setup:
Python flask enviornment set up according to the github example: https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/python/flask-fine-uploader-s3. I have set it up according to the setup. Do I need to do more? Create my own policy documents or is everything included in the app.py file?

The app is running and publicly available by it's url. This is the url I link to in the signature endpoint above.

I get the following error when I try to upload an image:

```
GET https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2116/3741/t/1/assets/edit.gif 404 ()
OPTIONS https://my-external-signature-server/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
s3.fine-uploader.js?11308611504760701622:165 [Fine Uploader 5.15.5] POST request for 0 has failed - response code 0
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] Received an empty or invalid response from the server!
[Fine Uploader 5.15.5] Policy signing failed.  Received an empty or invalid response from the server!
```

my-external-signature-server is of course a stand in term.

I hope someone has an idea what could be wrong?
I'll gladly provide more information if necessary.

Comment: There's a connection refused error for the signature endpoint... are you sure it's actually reachable?

Comment: Thanks Zeromus, I have figured out that my aws authentication instance is http (of course) and my website insist on it being a https.

Is it corret that there is no way to link to a http?